# Filter based on two columns of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has 4 columns separated by two groups `(ID_PROCESSO, ID_INSTANCIA_BPM)` and `(ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI, ID_PROCESSO_PAI)`.

If the second group `(ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI AND ID_PROCESSO_PAI)` is `null` and the first group of this record is not present as second group of a record where `ID_PROCESSO == ID_PROCESSO_PAI`, so it must be returned.

If the second group `(ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI AND ID_PROCESSO_PAI)` is `not null` and `ID_PROCESSO <> ID_PROCESSO_PAI`, so it must be returned.

For the sqlfiddle example, the return should respect the rules like

```
#|ID_PROCESSO|ID_INSTANCIA_BPM|ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI|ID_PROCESSO_PAI
1   3   2957    (null)  (null)  --Returned
2   5   2958    2957    3   --Returned
3   4   2960    (null)  (null)  --Returned
4   4   2975    (null)  (null)  --Returned
5   3   2976    (null)  (null)  --Removed by #10
6   3   2977    (null)  (null)  --Removed by #9
7   5   2978    2977    3   --Removed by #8
8   5   2979    2978    5   --Returned
9   3   2980    2977    3   --Returned
10  3   2981    2976    3   --Returned
11  4   2984    (null)  (null)  --Returned
```

So the result must be:

```
#|ID_PROCESSO|ID_INSTANCIA_BPM|ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI|ID_PROCESSO_PAI
1   3   2957    (null)  (null)  --Returned
2   5   2958    2957    3   --Returned
3   4   2960    (null)  (null)  --Returned
4   4   2975    (null)  (null)  --Returned
8   5   2979    2978    5   --Returned
9   3   2980    2977    3   --Returned
10  3   2981    2976    3   --Returned
11  4   2984    (null)  (null)  --Returned
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32c86/1

Anybody know if this is possible only with select or do I need a cursor to achieve this result?

Comment: The short answer is "No," you don't need to use a cursor.  As a first step, see if you can write a query to implement the rules and return the rows to be excluded.  If you can do that, the final result is ridiculously easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correct,

```
select *
from processes p1
where (p1.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI is null AND p1.ID_PROCESSO_PAI is null
      and
      not exists (select *
                  from processes p2
                  where p2.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI = p1.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM
                    and p2.ID_PROCESSO_PAI = p1.ID_PROCESSO 
                    and p2.ID_PROCESSO = p1.ID_PROCESSO)
      )
      or
      (p1.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI is not null AND ID_PROCESSO_PAI is not null 
      and
      not exists (select *
                  from processes p2
                  where p2.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM_PAI = p1.ID_INSTANCIA_BPM
                    and p2.ID_PROCESSO_PAI = p1.ID_PROCESSO 
                    )
      )
```

And in your input rows on sqlfiddle you missed 1 row:

```
insert into processes values (5,    '2979', '2978', 5);
```